# Eclipse breakpoint condition for objects

Tags: eclipse, breakpoints

I have a problem with the eclipse breakpoint condition pattern.
Regarding this code snippet

```
public void updateGateway(Gateway pGatewy) {
  mGateway = pGateway;
```

I want to stop the process only if

```
pGateway.getNumber()==123.
```

But the condition is without effect and I tested it already successful with this number(but without condition).

What I have to insert in the editor of the Breakpoint properties dialog? The checkbox Conditional is selected.

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update your condition**

> ```
> pGateway.getNumber()==123.
> ```

to

> `pGateway.getNumber()==123`

Choose **Suspend when true** option.

Conditional debugging can be run on my machine.  You can reference [here](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/breakpoints/ref-condition_option.htm).
[image]

Comment: damn I closed the line with ;